# How to set value and max attributes of progress tag using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

How to set value and max attributes of progress tag using angularjs

```
<progress value="500" max="1000">
```

I have tried using

```
<progress value="{{jdata.min}}" max="{{jdata.max}}"></progress>
```

jdata is holding json data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This HTML

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
       <progress value="{{jdata.min}}" max="{{jdata.max}}">
   </div>
</div>​
```

And this data in your controller

```
var App = angular.module('app', []);
App.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.jdata = {
        min: 500,
        max: 1000
    };
});
```

​

Check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/hKvNc/5/